# Trait Variation Not Found For UIButton attributed font

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, uitraitcollection, xcode10.1

Trait variation is shown when button's title font is Plain. Please see below image:

[image]

But when the title font is changed to attributed, the plus icon disappears. Please see below image:

[image]

Can anyone please help me with how to add trait variations for `UIButton` attributed title?

**Plese note:** The same is working fine for a `UILabel`. Please see below image:

[image]

**I am using Xcode 10.1.**

Comment: Well idk the answer of this, but it would be helpful if I can learn from this. Mind sharing whats trait variation or any article on it?

Comment: It's something which helps your designs adopts different device and orientations including iPad.